# "sudo: unknown user: postgres" when trying to create postgres user

Tags: macos, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, createuser

I'm using Mac 10.9.5 and PostgreSQL 9.3.4.  I'm following instructions for installing a third-party software package (Instructure Canvas) on my local machine) and the instructions say to execute:

```
sudo -u postgres createuser $USER
sudo -u postgres psql -c "alter user $USER with superuser" postgres
```

but upon executing the first command, I get the error

```
davea$ sudo -u postgres createuser $USER
sudo: unknown user: postgres
```

Other posts seemed to indicate I needed to prepend a "_" to my "postgres" user, but upon doing so, i get this error ...

```
davea$ sudo -u _postgres createuser $USER
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: FATAL:  role "_postgres" does not exist
```

Any ideas what I need to do to get this to work properly?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like whatever you installed has a system user named `_postgres` and a PostgreSQL user named `postgres`. Fun!

Try:

```
sudo -u _postgres createuser -U postgres myusername
```

(The numerous messy, conflicting and incompatible PostgreSQL installs used on OS X are a nightmare, argh).